# Ho to setup iOS Infobar in a cordova/phonegap project

Tags: xcode, cordova, ios7

I have created a cordova/phonegap project. With the new iOS 7, now the infobar lays above my header (dark blue). By default the infobar is in black font, how can I change it into white or any other color?

[image: Infobar iOS]

Thanks, Nik

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the links bellow.

http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/09/phonegap-and-cordova-with-ios-7/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=phonegap-and-cordova-with-ios-7

http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review